# Temporarily Disable ZFS ARC for Benchmarking

Tags: disk, zfs, storage, io, benchmarks

Is it possible to temporarily disable the ZFS ARC cache?

I am trying to benchmark a ZFS SSD array using `fio` and want to avoid ZFS caches (via the ARC) from skewing the results. The alternative of benchmarking using a file size much larger than the system memory (i.e. 64GB fio file on a system with 1x 32GB system RAM) will increase the benchmark duration dramatically.

*Using Ubuntu 19.10, `fio` 3.1.2 and ZFS on Linux 0.8.1*

Answer (score 0):

In ZFS that is not just filesystem, benchmarking is really hard and should always be simulation of future workload. So do writes that you are expecting, otherwise you made your system for something else than usage.

Since ARC and ZIL in RAM are things that ZFS rely heavily, those should never be taken out of load simulation. For analogy, we tested a new Ferrari but installed lawnmower engine to reduce fuel cost in long testing.

If you want to test with L2ARC and without, just remove L2ARC disk for testing time. Same for Intent Log device.
That should be done just to see if you need one.

Article to gather more information on; [Benchmarking ZFS](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/benchmarking-zfs.7928/)

Comment: How can we disable the ARC, or at least set it to a very small value? It's hard to blowout the ARC when the RAM size is 128 GB. Would like to avoid moving memory DIMM in and out of the system to reduce system RAM size, even then the smallest DIMM available on hand is 32GB which is moderately inconvenient to blow out.

Comment: Edited my question to ask about disabling ARC instead of L2ARC

Comment: echo "14359738368" > /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_arc_max (or what ever value you want to use). Or create tmpfs (ramdisk) to block memory before zfs is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very late answer, but since this question was never fully answered, I just wanted to note that the simplest way to "eliminate" ARC for testing is to do the following:

```
zfs set primarycache=none pool/dataset
zfs set secondarycache=none pool/dataset
```

My recommendation would be to do this for a testing dataset created for this purpose, e.g- `pool/test` rather than disabling for an existing dataset (or the root dataset), though depending upon how realistic you intend to make the test this may not be an option.

If you set these to none, make sure to check what the existing values are, and look for any datasets that may have local overrides. You can grab this quickly with `zfs get -rt filesystem primarycache,secondarycache pool`. The default is `all` (data and metadata).

As Pasi says though, the results of this kind of benchmarking may be limited, though if your goal is simply to test ZFS read/write speeds on a set of drives, then this may be sufficient.